# FancyBox 3: top positioning of images

Tags: image, fancybox, positioning

I have to position the image container at the top of the page, but there is no parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a small snippet in the docs of fancybox3, That works for me, but not for the navigation buttons. They are still in the middle of the page:

```
afterShow : function( instance, current, e ) {
  $('.fancybox-content').css('transform','translate3d(0px, 30px, 0px)');
}
```

Comment: You can reposition arrows using css, example, `.fancybox-navigation .fancybox-button { top: 0}`

Answer (score 0):

Spacing around content is controlled by CSS padding property of wrapping element. This is the default value for element containing an image:

```
.fancybox-slide--image {
    padding: 44px 0;
}

@media all and (max-height: 576px) {
    .fancybox-slide--image {
        padding: 6px 0;
    }
}
```

You can adjust that for your likening. As you can see, this gives greater flexibility that just some js option.

Comment: Hi Janis, thanks for your answer, but that doesnt work. I´ve made a screenshot that shows the problem: https://www.backend45.com/images/2019-02-21_08-17-50.png

Comment: Oh, you want to change vertical centering. This snippet could be used to adjust spacing, but, indeed, there is no option for disabling vertical centering.